# Fuzzy unit testing in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to write a set of "fuzzy" unit tests in python. So far I've been using `testtools`, but switching to a different framework would be fine.

My test suite is aiming to test the performance of image-processing algorithms. I'd like to be able to have tests report fuzzy pass states. In other words, the results are "good enough" but it might be useful to investigate.

I have something like this:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMyAlgorithm)
result = testtools.TestResult()

result.startTestRun()
try:
    suite.run(result)
finally:
    result.stopTestRun()
```

I'd like to use information in the `result` object to generate a report, but it looks like all of the information associated with passed tests has been tossed.

I'm wondering if I'm abusing the notion of a unit test to fit this sort of investigation.

Is there a standard way to perform this sort of testing in python?

Comment: This seems like there's a bit of an x-y problem here. What is your ultimate goal here? Reporting success or failure based on a percentage? Reporting?

Comment: `assertAlmostEqual` tests for approximate equality, maybe it could be used. Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal here is really reporting, get a tool which can generate a detailed report in xml format (e.g. `nosetests`; `py.test` likely has similar support), and process the report however you want in a second step.